# Deploying django to AWS Lambda connecting to RDS MySQL, showing error: NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined

Tags: mysql, django, lambda, zappa

Deploying django to AWS Lambda using zappa connecting to RDS MySQL,
not able to deploy
showing error:  **NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined:**

**zappa update dev** gives error:
*Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 502 response code*

AWS Cloudwatch logs:

> *name '_mysql' is not defined: NameError Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 609, in lambda_handler
> return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
> handler = cls()   File "/var/task/handler.py", line 146, in **init**
> wsgi_app_function = get_django_wsgi(self.settings.DJANGO_SETTINGS)   File "/var/task/zappa/ext/django_zappa.py", line 20, in
> get_django_wsgi
> return get_wsgi_application()   File "/var/task/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
> django.setup(set_prefix=False)   File "/var/task/django/**init**.py", line 24, in setup
> apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/var/task/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
> app_config.import_models()   File "/var/task/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
> self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 678, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> _call_with_frames_removed   File "/var/task/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in 
> from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager   File "/var/task/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py",
> line 47, in 
> class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):   File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 121, in **new**
> new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))   File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
> value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/var/task/django/db/models/options.py", line 208, in
> contribute_to_class
> self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())   File
> "/var/task/django/db/**init**.py", line 28, in **getattr**
> return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)   File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in **getitem**
> backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])   File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
> return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in
> import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "/var/task/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in 
> import MySQLdb as Database   File "/var/task/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 24, in 
> version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.**file**
> **NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined***

My ***settings.py*** DB config

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'raags-instance', # DB Instance created in AWS RDS
        'USER': 'xyz',
        'PASSWORD': 'passwordpassword',
        'HOST': '*********.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

For **DATABASES = {}** getting deployed successfully
Am new to zappa deployment and serverless architecture, Please assist, am not able to find the solution anywhere.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

The problem was due to .mysql file missing in MySQLdb directory

I tried a work around and importing pymysql and installing..
goto *django_project/django_project/**init**.py* file (the same dir where *settings.py* lives)

add the foll. code and deploy again, this worked for me

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```